# getting hour in groups - oracle - whats is wrong

Tags: oracle

whats is wrong with this query.
I need to get all hours of the 24 hours period to count hits per hour.
I want to make a case when 0-24 but I can not do the first work

```
SELECT
    (
    CASE WHEN (
           CAST(TO_CHAR(dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess, 'HH24') >= '00')
         AND
          CAST(TO_CHAR(dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess, 'HH24') < '01')
         )
        THEN ('00:00 as 01:00')
        ELSE '0' END
    ) as hour,        
    count(*)
FROM dg_user_acess
GROUP by hour
```

i get the error

Erro de SQL: ORA-00905: palavra-chave não encontrada
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

the table data is like this

```
pk| dt_user_acess
01| 2014-10-21 08:30:12
02| 2014-10-21 08:40:27
03| 2014-10-21 08:56:18
04| 2014-10-21 09:15:19
05| 2014-10-21 10:42:48
...
```

and the result I would like something like this (not write the case when all schedulesin query to not pollute the code)

```
'00:00 as 01:00' 0
'01:00 as 02:00' 0
'02:00 as 03:00' 0
'03:00 as 04:00' 0
'04:00 as 05:00' 0
'05:00 as 06:00' 0
'06:00 as 07:00' 0
'07:00 as 08:00' 0
'08:00 as 09:00' 3
'09:00 as 10:00' 1
'10:00 as 11:00' 1
'11:00 as 12:00' 0
'12:00 as 13:00' 0 
'13:00 as 14:00' 0 
'14:00 as 15:00' 0 
'15:00 as 16:00' 0 
'16:00 as 17:00' 0 
'17:00 as 18:00' 0 
'18:00 as 19:00' 0 
'19:00 as 20:00' 0 
'20:00 as 21:00' 0 
'21:00 as 22:00' 0 
'22:00 as 23:00' 0 
'23:00 as 23:59' 0
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? What error do you get? What data type are you trying to cast to, and which part - do you need the cast as well as the to_char? Your parentheses are also unbalanced.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected results; your query is so badly broken that it doesn't help explain the problem.

Comment: maybe now becomes clearer

Comment: the cast is to escapean error "00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"  and i see now This error occurs because the group by

Comment: and sorry for not asking correctly, I will try understand better how to use the forum to improve my participation

Answer (score 2):

> whats is wrong with this query [?]

You have many (more or less severe) issues with your query -- in no particular order:

- The correct syntax for `CAST`  is `CAST(value AS type)`
- You use `hour` as a column name, but it is a reserved word
- You compare *strings* where it is probably *numbers* that you should compare
- You seems to expect a "dense" result set, but as you don't use a join, there is no chance for the result set to have *more* rows than the original table (probably less in fact, as you `GROUP BY`)

---

Given your needs, you probably missed the [`EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function. In order to extract all the "hits" for an hour, you would write that:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess) as "hour"        
FROM dg_user_acess
```

As you need to `COUNT` them (and since you cannot use an alias in a `GROUP BY` clause) you might use a sub-query. Don't worry too much about that: Oracle is smart enough to optimize that kind of request:

```
SELECT "hour", count(*) "cnt"
FROM (
    SELECT
      EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess) as "hour"        
    FROM dg_user_acess
) V
GROUP BY "hour";
```

Finally, as you need a dense output (i.e.: with all hours in the range 0-23), my option would be to use a join on a generated table:

```
SELECT "hour", NVL("cnt",0) "cnt"
FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL "hour" FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 24
) CLOCK
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "hour", count(*) "cnt"
    FROM (
        SELECT
          EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess) as "hour"        
        FROM dg_user_acess
    ) V
    GROUP BY "hour"
) G
USING ("hour")
ORDER BY "hour";
```

All of this leads to rather complexly nested queries. But this has the benefit of being easy to write incrementally as you just see it. Now that I showed the basic building blocks, perhaps we could do a better job. Maybe that:

```
SELECT CLOCK."hour", COUNT(dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess) "cnt"
FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL "hour" FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 24
) CLOCK
LEFT JOIN dg_user_acess
ON CLOCK."hour" = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dg_user_acess.dt_user_acess)
GROUP BY CLOCK."hour"
ORDER BY CLOCK."hour";
```

Depending your schema and data, this might or might not perform better than the previous version. Feel free to take some time to experiment all these queries on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/678a5/17

Comment: ty for answering, i will not test it now, because the answer i posted is working well. when i have free time i will test your answer

Answer (score 0):

> i get some result changing the group by and the condition of the case (and remove the cast).
>
> > > I do not know if it's the best way to do this, but it worked

```
 SELECT 
  (
    CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '00:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '01:00' ) THEN ('00:00 as 01:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '01:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '02:00' ) THEN ('01:00 as 02:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '02:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '03:00' ) THEN ('02:00 as 03:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '03:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '04:00' ) THEN ('03:00 as 04:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '04:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '05:00' ) THEN ('04:00 as 05:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '05:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '06:00' ) THEN ('05:00 as 06:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '06:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '07:00' ) THEN ('06:00 as 07:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '07:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '08:00' ) THEN ('07:00 as 08:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '08:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '09:00' ) THEN ('08:00 as 09:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '09:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '10:00' ) THEN ('09:00 as 10:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '10:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '11:00' ) THEN ('10:00 as 11:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '11:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '12:00' ) THEN ('11:00 as 12:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '12:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '13:00' ) THEN ('12:00 as 13:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '13:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '14:00' ) THEN ('13:00 as 14:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '14:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '15:00' ) THEN ('14:00 as 15:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '15:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '16:00' ) THEN ('15:00 as 16:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '16:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '17:00' ) THEN ('16:00 as 17:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '17:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '18:00' ) THEN ('17:00 as 18:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '18:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '19:00' ) THEN ('18:00 as 19:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '19:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '20:00' ) THEN ('19:00 as 20:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '20:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '21:00' ) THEN ('20:00 as 21:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '21:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '22:00' ) THEN ('21:00 as 22:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '22:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '23:00' ) THEN ('22:00 as 23:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '23:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '23:59' ) THEN ('23:00 as 23:59')         
        ELSE '0' END
    ) as hora,
    count(*) as total
  FROM dg_usuario_acesso  
  JOIN dg_usuario_sessao 
  ON dg_usuario_sessao.cd_usuario_sessao     = dg_usuario_acesso.cd_usuario_sessao
  WHERE dg_usuario_acesso.dt_usuario_acesso >= to_date('2014-09-19 00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi')
  AND dg_usuario_acesso.dt_usuario_acesso   <= to_date('2014-09-20 15:07', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi')
  AND dg_usuario_sessao.cd_usuario NOT      IN (0,1,138)
  group by (CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '00:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '01:00' ) THEN ('00:00 as 01:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '01:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '02:00' ) THEN ('01:00 as 02:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '02:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '03:00' ) THEN ('02:00 as 03:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '03:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '04:00' ) THEN ('03:00 as 04:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '04:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '05:00' ) THEN ('04:00 as 05:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '05:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '06:00' ) THEN ('05:00 as 06:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '06:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '07:00' ) THEN ('06:00 as 07:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '07:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '08:00' ) THEN ('07:00 as 08:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '08:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '09:00' ) THEN ('08:00 as 09:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '09:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '10:00' ) THEN ('09:00 as 10:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '10:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '11:00' ) THEN ('10:00 as 11:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '11:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '12:00' ) THEN ('11:00 as 12:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '12:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '13:00' ) THEN ('12:00 as 13:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '13:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '14:00' ) THEN ('13:00 as 14:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '14:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '15:00' ) THEN ('14:00 as 15:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '15:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '16:00' ) THEN ('15:00 as 16:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '16:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '17:00' ) THEN ('16:00 as 17:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '17:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '18:00' ) THEN ('17:00 as 18:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '18:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '19:00' ) THEN ('18:00 as 19:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '19:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '20:00' ) THEN ('19:00 as 20:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '20:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '21:00' ) THEN ('20:00 as 21:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '21:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '22:00' ) THEN ('21:00 as 22:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '22:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '23:00' ) THEN ('22:00 as 23:00')
         WHEN (TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') >= '23:00' AND TO_CHAR(dg_usuario_acesso.DT_USUARIO_ACESSO, 'HH24:Mi') < '23:59' ) THEN ('23:00 as 23:59')
        ELSE '0' END
    )
order by 1
```

and I got the result I would like

```
hour            Total hits
00:00 as 01:00  10
04:00 as 05:00  8
07:00 as 08:00  4
08:00 as 09:00  14
09:00 as 10:00  84
10:00 as 11:00  25
11:00 as 12:00  14
12:00 as 13:00  7
13:00 as 14:00  5
14:00 as 15:00  7
15:00 as 16:00  22
16:00 as 17:00  19
17:00 as 18:00  28
18:00 as 19:00  7
19:00 as 20:00  16
21:00 as 22:00  2
23:00 as 23:59  2
```